# pymysql and writing a pandas dataframe back to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

I am in Python and have a Pandas dataframe called Office_RX.

I am connected to mysql via pymysql.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127....', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='ABCD')
c = conn.cursor()
```

I want to write the Office_RX dataframe back into the MYSQL db I am connected to.

I am using this code:

```
sql.write_frame(Office_RX, conn=conn, name='Office_RX', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

But I get the error: TypeError: write_frame() takes at least 3 arguments (4 given)

Can tell what I am doing wrong. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument in [`write_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.sql.write_frame.html) is con rather than conn:

```
sql.write_frame(Office_RX, con=conn, name='Office_RX', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

*This function accepts `**kwargs`, hence the vaguely cryptic error message.*

Comment: Nice catch! Thought about older (0.9 and earlier) versions usage

Comment: @alko I've seen this confusing python error message before, and thought: "I've passed 4... why are you complaining I need at least 3... arrgh!"